# C# UWP How to set the background behind the application to black

Tags: c#, xaml, background

If a user clicks on the corner of my app, and resizes, the app stays the same size, but the area behind expands.  Same for Maximize. The area behind is white.

Ideally, I would like to disable resizing completely! But, given that I have not been able to figure out how to stop it, how do I **change the area behind to black**.

If I change the Page to Background="Black" the white stays and there is a black area offset and just totally wrong.  Picture 1

Picture 2 is what I get with the XAML below.  It is also what I get with a maximize, its just full screen.

Side question: Is there no way do just have the app that wont change size?

**Sorry.. I thought** this was going to be a really simple thing to answer.

---

[image: picture 1 was when I removed the line in the Pages set up and preplaced it with background=Black]

[[image: picture 2 just normal .. you get a white background], but I did put backbround=Black In the first two tags <border> and <Grid> That didn't do anything in the[2]]

And Here is the  opening XAML.  I cut out the stuff Storyboards that are in the Pages resources... too much info

```
<Page
x:Class="ScqWander.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ScqWander"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Width="1104"    Height="700" 
MaxWidth="1104" MinHeight="700"    
Loaded="Page_Loaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources></Page.Resources>

<Border x:Name="AppContainerForCentering"  
        Width="1104" Height="696"
        BorderBrush="GreenYellow" 
        BorderThickness="4" >

    <Grid x:Name="MainBoard" Background="Black" 
      Height="690" Width="auto"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"          
     >   
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1084"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="gridMainDesignArea"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="auto" Width="auto" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="230"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="780"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="BabyMonOnBar" Width="28" Height="28"
            Source="Assets/Images/Play/MonsterBaby.png" 
            Grid.Column="2"                 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>               

                all the other XAML goes here
    <Grid>
   <Border> 
  <Page>
```

Comment: Add a couple of screenshots, please. And add a little more context in the xaml code.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. [Why UWP ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush is always white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206027/why-uwp-applicationpagebackgroundthemebrush-is-always-white).

Comment: I looked at the link. Unless I missed something, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  I was setting the width and height in the first tag  assuming that would be the correct place.  It Was!

What I did Not know was this

- **REMOVE** the **width**="" and **height**=""
- Replace with  **d:DesignWidth**="1194" **d:DesignHeight**="758"

and then set the background to black once I had the other figured out